# Apache camel FTP standalone programme

Tags: apache-camel

Hello I am trying to write a simple standalone java FTP programme that downloads files from FTP server location to my local machine using Apache Camel. When I run is I see that it runs forever and the actual file transfer is not taking place. What could be the issue?

```
private static class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
           @Override
       public void configure() throws Exception {
           from("sftp://serverIpAddress?password=passwd&binary=true")
           .process(new Processor() {
               public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                   System.out.println("Invoked timer at " + new Date());

               }
           }) 
           .tracing()
           .to("file://localmachine/Users/localFtpOutput/")
           ;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Any useful information in the traces? Could you share the output?

Answer (score 2):

Wild guess : don't you need to provide a username to access your ftp ?

```
from("sftp://username@serverIpAddress?password=passwd&binary=true")
```

If you don't camel will try to log with anonymous as username and will use no password (according to the [doc](http://camel.apache.org/ftp.html))